# Firebase (reactjs) reads from database too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm reading from my firebase realtime database when my component loads to update a state with the returned data. Whenever the component loads, it gets the data from the database 8 times, and this causes React to give an error since the state is updated too many times in quick succession.

I've tried using both the `onValue` listener and the `get` function, and they both do the same thing on page load. If instead, I do not call them on page load, and either `onValue` or `get` runs manually or from the database being updated, it runs **only once** as expected.

The component:

```js
export default function FoodItem(props) {
    const [foods, setFoods] = useState()
    const db = getDatabase()

    // creating the onValue listener (below) creates the same issue

    // const mealRef = ref(db, (props.userId + "/" + props.date + "/" + props.meal))
    // onValue(mealRef, (snapshot) => {
    //     const data = snapshot.val()
    //     console.log(data)  
    //     setFoods(data)
    // })

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("getFoods")
        const dbRef = ref(getDatabase())
        
        get(child(dbRef, (props.userId + "/" + props.date + "/" + props.meal))).then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log(snapshot.val())
                // setFoods(data)
            } else {
                console.log("No data available")
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

[The console output from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miHcB.png)

If instead of using `useEffect`, I call `get` with a function (for example, with `onClick`, it only gets the data once as expected:

```js
    function getFoods() {
        console.log("getFoods")
        const dbRef = ref(getDatabase())
        
        get(child(dbRef, (props.userId + "/" + props.date + "/" + props.meal))).then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log(snapshot.val())
                // setFoods(data)
            } else {
                console.log("No data available")
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
    }
```

How do I make it only run once when the component loads?

Comment: Mine fires 104 times for a simple counter update

Comment: I'd love some info on this too..